# Printwriter problems?

Tags: java, input, copy, output, printwriter

I'm trying to write a file that copies data from one user-inputted file into two other separate user-inputted files, however the something isn't going right and nothing's being copied. I know the first line is being read because I edited the code to check and display if anything from the first file was reading (it was) but again, nothing is copying. I'm learning from a book and would appreciate any help I could get. Thanks a lot!

Here's the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class FileIO
{
        // This method writes data from a file to other files
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter input file name:");
            String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Enter output file name:");
            String filename2 = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Enter another output file name (append) :");
            String filename3 = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename2);
            FileWriter outputFile2 = new FileWriter(filename3, true);
            PrintWriter outputfile2 = new PrintWriter(outputFile2);

            File myfile = new File(filename);
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myfile);

            while (inputFile.hasNext()){
                    String morelines = inputFile.nextLine();
                    outputFile.print(morelines);
                    outputfile2.print(morelines);
            }
            outputFile.close();
            outputfile2.close();
            inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `flush()` on the two output files before you `close()` them.

Comment: FYI, you have `outputFile2` and `outputfile2`, which is unnecessarily confusing. I recommend at least renaming `outputfile2` to `outputFile3`, if not renaming all three to more descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the code you provided to work just fine. [Jason C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616460/jason-c) suggested calling `flush()` on your PrintWriters before closing them, and I concur.